# JavaFX ImageView via FXML does not work

Tags: image, imageview, javafx, fxml

I have a problem with loading Images with `ImageView` on FXML.

My controller class:

```
public class BoxViewController {
    @FXML
    private Label label_boxID;

    @FXML
    private ImageView boximage;

    public void initData(ObservableList<BoxProperty> observableList,
                         BoxService sBox, 
                         TableView tableview) {
        this.label_boxID.setText(
            String.valueOf(this.boxproperty.getPboxid()));

        Image image = new Image("boximage.jpg");
        this.boximage = new ImageView();
        this.boximage.setImage(image);
    }
}
```

So, setting the label with a text works, but the image won't appear in my ImageView.
For the ImageView, I added an ID to the FXML file:

```
 <ImageView fx:id="boximage" 
            disable="false" 
            fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0"
            layoutX="69.0" layoutY="322.0" 
            pickOnBounds="true" 
            preserveRatio="true" />
```

I'm confused why this is not working because the label works, but the image won't load.
I also checked whether `boximage` isn't null, but it isn't. There are also no Exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage;
bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File(this.path));
Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null);
this.boximage.setImage(image);
```

Answer (score 14):

Maybe it's a source image location issue. According to the comments at [this website](http://zoranpavlovic.blogspot.sk/2012/06/javafx-2-load-image.html), from ***"Maxim"***, if you use `new Image("boximage.jpg");`, the root directory is the *main project folder* and e.g for `scene.getStylesheets().add("login.css");` the root folder is `src`.
Maybe you could try this:

```
Image img = new Image("file:boximage.jpg");
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(img);
```

Try to move the source image to the main project folder for this code

Just for testing purpose, try to load that image from **FXML**:

```
<ImageView id="boxImage" ...>    
   <image>
      <Image url="@boximage.jpg" />
   </image>
</ImageView>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, well, I used the BufferdImage from the API to resolve that problem. Actually, I tried your version too, it works also with the FXML-version, the problem was the "loading" of the image into the scene and not reading out of the file. I used BufferedImage because the picture was loaded dynamically.